# c++ map, is it safe to remove elements while iterating using extended for loop?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a map where key is integer and value is a vector of integer. Now these vector contains some duplicate elements and I want to remove them. So, I am using

```
sort(map.begin(),map.end())
map.erase(unique(map.begin(),map.end()),map.end());
```

everything is working fine. But when I use extended for loop like

```
for(auto i:map)
```

then this doesn't work, but it works when I use:

```
for(auto i=map.begin();i!=map.end();i++)
```

below is full code:

```
#define loopi(i,n) for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
map<int,vector<int>>m;
    m[0]={1,22,22,3};
    m[2]={2,1,11,11,1,6};
    m[5]={2,2,2,33,5};
    for(auto i:m){
        cout<<i.second.size()<<endl;
        sort(i.second.begin(),i.second.end());
        i.second.erase(unique(i.second.begin(),i.second.end()),i.second.end());
        cout<<i.second.size()<<endl;
        loopi(j,i.second.size()) cout<<i.second[j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(auto i:m){
        cout<<i.second.size()<<endl;
        loopi(j,i.second.size()) cout<<i.second[j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

I get output:

```
4
3
1 3 22 
6
4
1 2 6 11 
5
3
2 5 33 

4
1 22 22 3 
6
2 1 11 11 1 6 
5
2 2 2 33 5
```

And using this:

```
    for(auto i=m.begin();i!=m.end();i++){
        cout<<i->second.size()<<endl;
        sort(i->second.begin(),i->second.end());
        i->second.erase(unique(i->second.begin(),i->second.end()),i->second.end());
        cout<<i->second.size()<<endl;
        loopi(j,i->second.size()) cout<<i->second[j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(auto i=m.begin();i!=m.end();i++){
        cout<<i->second.size()<<endl;
        loopi(j,i->second.size()) cout<<i->second[j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

And for this case, I get output:

```
4
3
1 3 22 
6
4
1 2 6 11 
5
3
2 5 33 

3
1 3 22 
4
1 2 6 11 
3
2 5 33
```

So, in the first case, it is not removing the elements.

Comment: I don't get the question.  You're not removing anything from the map.  You are just changing the value.

Comment: I am using erase.

Comment: You are using erase on the vectors, not the map.

Comment: `for(auto i:m)` - `i` is a **_copy_** of key-value pair. You only ever erase elements in that copy. You should take `i` by reference : `for(auto& i: m)`

Comment: [std::map::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) returns a new iterator that you can use to continue iterating. I suggest you *use* it.

Comment: Thanks got it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution performs the same operation, but on a copy of your actual elements that is thrown away afterwards. In `for(auto i:m)`, `i` is a `pair<int, vector<int>>`, and since you don't take it by reference (i.e. `for(auto& i : m)`), the `vector` you're modifying in that loop is a copy of the original `vector` you have.

Your second example works because you're using iterators, which don't create a copy of your data.